# Change connection string Linked Service in Azure Data Factory v2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Data Factory V2 to integrate data from multiple on-premise mySql database. Is it possible to define just one mysql linked service and then modify the connection string (server name, credential, integration runtime) during runtime. My plan is to use lookup activity to read list of connection strings and then use for-each activity to iterate over that list to pull data from each database using copy activity.

Is it possible to do such things, preferably using the Azure data Factory UI? or Should I use .NET SDK to do that?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working on enabling parameter support for Linked Service so you can accomplish the scenario described today.  Please stay tuned!  Today you still need to use specific connection strings in Linked Service definition.

Comment: Thanks for the information, do you have an estimate on when this feature will be available?

Comment: I don't have an exact ETA but expect it to be there in the next few weeks.