# Use parameters in place of linked service name in Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-data-factory

My question is slightly similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49814312/change-connection-string-linked-service-in-azure-data-factory-v2) however adequately different to merit a new thread.

I have a requirement to extract data from a number of different on-premises SQL Server instances over the internet. I am using Azure Data-Factory 2 and the Integration Runtime to access data from these servers.

The problem is that i will have many pipelines to manage and update. I want to have a single Data Factory process which uses parameters for linked service names.

*Is it possible to have 1 pipeline which uses a parameter to reference a linked service name which is updated before re-executing the pipeline?*

I am struggling to find a useful article on how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Reference name can’t be parametied. But making linked Service support parameters is in the plan as the post you mentioned said.